# Telerik reportviewer not showing the report

Tags: c#, telerik, reportviewer

I have an issue in displaying a report using reportviewer. A am generating a report programatically using stored procedure and the report has data as well if I debug.

```
report.DataSource = Adapter.ExceptionProjectedQuotePastProjectedCloseDate(GroupList.SelectedText.ToString(), TimePeriodList.SelectedText.ToString(), startDateTimePicker.Value.ToString(), endDateTimePicker.Value.ToString());
Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
reportSource.ReportDocument = report;
reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

This is the code i am using to generate the report and I am really confuse about it.

Comment: What do you not see? The report viewer or the data in the report?

Comment: Try getting rid of the call to `RefreshReport()`.

Comment: report inside the reportviewer, but when I debug the datasource has been set into the report. @FeliceM